# Is it possible to partially restrict FTP access to a site?

Tags: security, ftp, hosting

Is it possible to partially restrict FTP access to a site?

I have a website where I would like users to be able to edit and upload webpages. However, some pages should not be changed, e.g. the first page should remain unchanged.

Is it possible to restrict permits to change and upload only certain pages if other users also have the FTP details? (I am the only one who has access to the cpanel of the web hosting service).

http://goo.gl/EdMrJ

Answer (score 1):

Simple - the files you don't want changing need to be owned by a different user than people are logging in to the FTP server with.  Then the FTP logins won't be able to overwrite them.

Comment: I think the service I'm using allows only one account...

Comment: Then no, it's unlikely you will be able to do it.  You would be best off providing some kind of web interface to upload files - that way you can have full control over it programatically.